# Asp.net MVC Membership starter kit

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have downloaded and installed membership starter kit from codeplex. Now when I create new project I don't see MVC mebership starter kit in list of templates. How do I create new project based on this starter kit  ?

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like it's been updated since preview 5...

The default ASP.NET MVC project that is created when you install the release version of [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/MVC/download/) includes integration with the membership system.

Comment: Only the registration, logon and change password are included. All users and roles administration are lost.

Comment: That's possibly the case, however the API for administering users and roles is well defined on MSDN, and these sorts of screens are fairly trivial to knock out if you need them.

Answer (score 1):

Grab the new release that works with MVC 1.0

Answer (score 0):

You can make a copy of that Starter Kits code base into a new trunk/src directory.  Then open the solution and hack away!  That is the normal process any ways.